# Functional analysis: Why $|[x,y]|\leq [x,x]^{1/2}[y,y]^{1/2}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\varepsilon>0$. We denote $[x,y]:=\langle \varepsilon x+Ax,y\rangle$ where $A$ is symmetric and $A\geq 0$. Why do we have that $$\big|[x,y]\big|\leq [x,x]^{1/2}[y,y]^{1/2}\ \ \ ?$$

The hint is to use Cauchy-Schwarz on $\langle \varepsilon x+Ax,y\rangle$, but when I do it I get
$$\big|[x,y]\big|^2\leq \langle\varepsilon x+Ax,\varepsilon x+Ax\rangle\langle y,y\rangle$$ 
whereas I would like to have $$\langle\varepsilon x+Ax,x\rangle\langle\varepsilon y+Ay,y\rangle.$$

**Question :** How can I prove my inequality ?

Comment: Is $\varepsilon$ a scalar or a vector?

Comment: You don't have additional hypothesis on $A$ like positiveness?

Comment: @Jean-PierreMerx: You right, I forget this hypothesis. So $A\geq 0$.

Comment: I can't tell... why is $[x,x] = \langle \epsilon x + Ax, x \rangle$ but  $[y,y] = \langle \epsilon y + Ay, \color{green}{\mathbf{\epsilon}} y \rangle$ ? Using your definition I got $[x,x] = \langle x + \epsilon + Ax , x \rangle $.  So I am even more confused.

Comment: I corrected it ! Sorry for this mistakes in notation. It's $[y,y]=\langle \varepsilon y+Ay, y\rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've corrected your notation fully. For any fixed $\varepsilon > 0$, the form $[x,y]$ defines an inner product on $X$. The properties are easy to verify. Therefore, by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
                 |[x,y]| \le [x,x]^{1/2}[y,y]^{1/2},\;\;\; x,y \in X.
$$
In terms of $A$, the above becomes
$$
           |(\varepsilon x + Ax,y)| \le (\varepsilon x + Ax,x)^{1/2}(\varepsilon y + Ay,y)^{1/2}
$$
The above hols for all $\varepsilon > 0$; so you may let $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$ to also obtain
$$
                     |(Ax,y)| \le (Ax,x)^{1/2}(Ay,y)^{1/2}.
$$
I suspect that's the end result they're steering you toward.

Comment: That's the perfect answer :-) So every thing is about to show that $[\cdot ,\cdot ]$ is an inner product, and then it's done :-) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is positive definite then we could define a new inner product (or at least a bilinear form) $\langle x,h\rangle' = \langle x | \color{red}{A} + \color{red}{\epsilon \, I} | y \rangle =\langle ( \color{red}{A} + \color{red}{\epsilon \, I})x | y \rangle = [x,y]$. Here I use [bra-ket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) notation for to make things look symmetric.

If $A$ is symmetric and positive definite, all the eigenvalues $\lambda > 0$ are positive so $A + \epsilon I$ is also symmetric and positive definite with eigenvalues $\lambda + \epsilon > 0$.  Therefore $[x,y]$ is also an inner product and satisfies Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

---

Here is standard proof for $\big|[x,y]\big|\leq [x,x]^{1/2}[y,y]^{1/2}$:

> We can verify that everywhere along the line $x + ty$ with $t \in \mathbb{R}$:
>
> $$\langle x+ty | A + \epsilon \, I | x+ty \rangle
> = t^2 \langle y |\dots | y \rangle
> + 2t  \langle x | \dots | y \rangle
> + \langle x | \dots | x \rangle \geq 0$$
>
> and since the discriminant is positive, we must have Cauchy-Schwarz here also.

---

Did I understand your notation correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be honest I don't understand your notation at all. What do you mean by $\langle x,h\rangle '$ and $\langle x\mid A+(1+\varepsilon)I\mid y\rangle$ ? I have never seen such notation.

Comment: it's just bra-ket notation.  It's just another way to write your definition emphasizing that $A$ is symmetric.